# guidelines for htaccess code to transition users to new website

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Suppose I have an old website with 10 webpages, and I want to deprecate it and move visitors to a new website with 100 webpages.

Two of the webpages of the old website map directly to two corresponding webpages on the new website. All other pages on the old website should go to the new website's home page. How to set that up?

I know I can use `.htaccess` in the public_html folder of the old website to create some permanent redirect rules for individual pages. So for the two pages that need to map one-to-one, I can do:

```
Redirect 301 /oldfile1.htm http://www.example.net/newfile1.htm
Redirect 301 /def/oldfile2.htm http://www.example.net/123/456/newfile2.htm
```

But what about all the other webpages on the old website? This is where my knowledge of `.htaccess` lacks. Does the `.htaccess` stop executing when it reaches one of the redirects above? If so, then perhaps I simply place the following AFTER the above code to catch the remaining pages?

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.net/
```

Or, something else? Also, will the redirect directly above map all webpages it sees to the home page of the new website (I assume so), or a matching directory/webpage page on the new website? -- That is, I don't want the situation where http://www.olddomain.com/abc/Oldfile1234.html takes users to http://www.example.net/abc/Oldfile1234.html on the new website (rather, it should take users to http://www.example.net) since most webpages do not map one-to-one.

Lastly, in the `.htaccess` file on the old website public_html directory, how to account for users coming from `https` versus `http`, and `www` versus `non-www` URLs?

I'm hoping there's common strategy people use for this sort of thing, since it should be fairly common, so I don't have to re-invent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `RedirectMatch` for precise matching using regular expressions. You can place these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfile1\.htm$ http://www.example.net/newfile1.htm
RedirectMatch 301 ^/def/oldfile2\.htm$ http://www.example.net/123/456/newfile2.htm
RedirectMatch 301 ^ http://www.example.net/
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava. I can't tell from your example code, but does it handle users visiting the old website from `https` as well as `http`, and also coming from `www` as well as `non-www` URLs?

Comment: Yes it takes care of all those cases.